# Python 3 + QT. Проблема с прорисовкой гуя, зависание

Tags: python, gui, qt

Разрабатываю один питон проект с использованием гуя при поддержке `Qt`. 
столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
while True:
    res = self.file.load("file.txt", isList=False)
    self.log("Ожидаем ввод")
    print("Ожидаем ввод")
    if res: 
        break
    else:
        self.log("Ждём")
        print("Ждём")               
        time.sleep(5)
```

Дело в том, что в консоль мне пишется принт "Ждём" и "Ожидаем ввода", но гуй дохнет намертво. Просто зависает и все.
С чем может быть связана проблема?

Comment: Извините, а что вы хотели? Крутите цикл (из которого, как я понимаю, выхода нет, а гую управление не передаёте. Как он может что-то делать без помощи процессора?

Comment: уже интереснее... что значит "урпавление не передаёте"? нужно его апдейтить в теле цикла, или есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: Такие вещи нужно запускать в дочернем потоке.

Comment: @1101_debian Ну если несколько потоков, то да. @izengardjke я qt не знаю, но в других гуях обычно есть подобные вызовы, служащие для обработки накопившихся событий.

Comment: [пример кода с  использованием фонового потока и сигналов в qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812982/23044)