# Обновление виджета QLabel PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как обновить виджет с фотографией - `QLabel`, библиотеки `PyQt5` в `python 3.6`. Смысл заключается в том, что сокет получает `bytes` фотографии и нужно при каждом получении обновлять фотографию в окне gui.

Код gui:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.wiget_photo()

    def wiget_photo(self):
        self.img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo)) #открытие bytes фото (библиотека PIL)
        self.qimage = ImageQt(self.img)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.qimage) #формотирование bytes фото в pixmap для setPixmap
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl.resize(500, 500) #размер виджета
        self.lbl.move(50, 50) #расположение виджета
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: [пример кода где картинка в QLabel вращается по нажатию клавиши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758483/23044) (`label.setPixmap()`)

Comment: [пример кода, где по нажатию кнопки картинка меняется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721290/23044)

Comment: [пример как удалённую картинку через http получить в памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706255/23044) (`Image.open(r.raw)`). У вас в коде уже есть и setPixmap и Image.open — какие у вас конкретно сложности с обновлением картинки при получении данных через сокет?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы показывать картинки, полученные через сокет, можно принимать картинки в фоновом потоке, используя простой сокет сервер (в общем случае, Qt позволяет сервер в цикле событий запустить в том же потоке) и получив картинку послать сигнал, чтобы отобразить картинку в GUI:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

def server(signal_obj, host='localhost', port=29044):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # reuse sockets in TIME_WAIT state
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen()
    signal_obj.server_started.emit(host, port)
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()  # XXX add error handling
        with conn, conn.makefile('rb') as file:  # one client at a time
            signal_obj.got_image.emit(addr, file.read())  # image received

class SignalObject(QObject):
    server_started = pyqtSignal(str, int)  # host, port
    got_image = pyqtSignal(tuple, bytes)   # addr, image data

    def receive_images(self):
        server(self)

class ImageViewer(QLabel):
    def on_server_start(self, host, port):
        self.setText(f'Waiting for images on {host}:{port}')
        self.adjustSize()

    def on_received_image(self, addr, image_data):
        self.setWindowTitle('Image from {}:{}'.format(*addr))
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(image_data)
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# run server in a background thread
thread = QThread()
signal_obj = SignalObject()  # communicate with GUI using signals
signal_obj.moveToThread(thread)
thread.started.connect(signal_obj.receive_images)

image_viewer = ImageViewer()
image_viewer.setWindowTitle('Show Images from socket')
signal_obj.server_started.connect(image_viewer.on_server_start)
signal_obj.got_image.connect(image_viewer.on_received_image)
image_viewer.show()
thread.start()       # start server
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Чтобы послать картинку при запущенном приложении:

```
$ nc localhost 29044 < /path/to/image.png
```

В коде две основных части:

1. `server()` ожидает по указанному адресу (host, port) новые соединения. Когда клиент подключается, сервер читает данные и публикует их как `got_image`  сигнал:

   ```
   signal_obj.got_image.emit(addr, file.read())
   ```
2. GUI, которое подписано на этот сигнал:

   ```
   signal_obj.got_image.connect(image_viewer.on_received_image)
   ```

   показывает новую картинку, используя `Pixmap.loadFromData` метод. [Отображение картинок на экран PyQt5 доступных как bytes](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/742683/23044).

В Qt у каждого объекта, есть свой поток (thread affinity), чтобы `SignalObject.receive_images` слот выполнялся в фоновом потоке, используется `signal_obj.moveToThread(thread)` вызов. [Background thread with QThread in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6783194/4279).

Не обязательно `QThread` использовать, посылка сигналов является thread-safe, можно из обычного Питон-потока сигналы посылать, [пример кода](https://gist.github.com/zed/fd292613a51bc55f224b6d74f84fc316).

Comment: такой вопрос а в `windows` какая команда будет чтобы послать картинку?

Comment: @Twiss netcat и на Windows есть, но это просто пример вместо настоящего клиента, который картинки посылает.

Comment: @Twiss: вот пример клиента на баше: `exec 3<> /dev/tcp/localhost/29044 && cat image.png >&3 && exec 3>&-`

Comment: что можно упростить до `cat image.png >/dev/tcp/localhost/29044`

Comment: @Twiss ясно ли как [`request_finished` сигнал из примера](https://gist.github.com/zed/fd292613a51bc55f224b6d74f84fc316) работает? (в каком потоке отправляется сигнал? (Thread, Pool) В каком потоке слот (`w.display`) вызывается?

Comment: на самом деле не очень понятно как это вообще работает(т.е. сама библиотека `socket`) т.к. я ее даже ни разу не использовал. Вот сейчас намерен начать. Так что по большей части мне нужно сначала это заучить)

Comment: @Twiss socket это относительно низкоуровневый [широкораспространённый] интерфейс, который полезно знать. В более сложных случаях, чтобы велосипед не изобретать, вместо своего adhoc протокола, можно готовые реализации (к примеру) http-протокола использовать (http-сервер запустить). Какой протокол, библиотеки выбрать от задачи зависит.

Answer (score 1):

Пример обновлении `QLabel` при помощи функции [`setText()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) раз в секунду.

В вашем случае обновление будет при получении фотографии.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.i = 0
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(lay)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def tick(self):
        self.i += 1
        self.label.setText("Значение равно {}".format(self.i))
        if self.i == 10:
            self.label.setText("Подсчет окончен")
            self.timer.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```