# Как передать параметры в поток PyQt5?

Tags: python, ооп, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты

Есть форма с двумя полями для ввода параметров и одной кнопкой:

```
...
signal_start_connect = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

def init_main_tab(self):
    self.comLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel('COM порт')
    self.comEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()    #сюда вводим параметр
    self.speedLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel('Скорость')
    self.speedEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()  #и сюда вводим параметр
    self.connectBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Подключиться')
    self.main_layout.addWidget(self.comLbl)
    self.main_layout.addWidget(self.comEdit)
    self.main_layout.addWidget(self.speedLbl)
    self.main_layout.addWidget(self.speedEdit)
    self.main_layout.addWidget(self.connectBtn)

    self.ConnectAllValues = [self.comEdit.text(), self.speedEdit.text()]
    self.signal_start_connect.connect(self.connectBtn, lambda fields=self.ConnectAllValues: self.read_values(fields))
```

И есть функция, которая считывает эти параметры и передает в поток (создан отдельный файл с классом `XBeeConnect(QtCore.QThread)`), в него в `XBeeConnect` передаются данные:

```
def read_values(self, fields):
# функция считывания параметров
    self.ConnectValues = []
    for i in fields:
        item = i.itemText(i.currentIndex())
        self.ConnectValues.append(item)

    # Отправка в поток параметры подключения
    self.xbeeConnect = XBeeConnect(self.init_main_tab)
    self.xbeeConnect.com = str("COM" + self.ConnectValues[0])
    self.xbeeConnect.speed = int(self.ConnectValues[1])
    self.signal_start_connect2.connect(self.xbeeConnect, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    self.xbeeConnect.start()
```

При *PyQt4* было написано так:

```
self.connect(self.connectBtn, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                 lambda fields=self.ConnectAllValues: 
self.read_values(fields))
```

Далее функция `read_values()` считывала данные и отправляла в поток, с помощью таких строчек:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.MainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MainWidget)
        self.MainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.MainWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle(u'Программа управления модулями XBee S2')
        self.init_main_tab()

    def init_main_tab(self):
        self.comLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel('COM порт')
        self.comEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.speedLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel('Скорость')
        self.speedEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.connectBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Подключиться')
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.comLbl)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.comEdit)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.speedLbl)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.speedEdit)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.connectBtn)
        self.ConnectAllValues = [self.comEdit.text(), self.speedEdit.text()]
        self.connect(self.connectBtn, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                     lambda fields=self.ConnectAllValues: self.read_values(fields))

    def read_values(self, fields):
        """Функция считывания и передачи значений для подключения к модулю"""
        self.ConnectValues = []
        for i in fields:
            item = i.itemText(i.currentIndex())
            self.ConnectValues.append(item)

        #Отправка в поток параметры подключения
        self.xbeeConnect = XBeeConnect(self.OpenConnectDialog)
        self.xbeeConnect.com = str("COM" + self.ConnectValues[0])
        self.xbeeConnect.speed = int(self.ConnectValues[1])
        self.connect(self.xbeeConnect, QtCore.SIGNAL('SendData(QString)'), self.logMessage, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.xbeeConnect.start()
```

Нужно также только для PyQt5. 
Пробовал создать отдельный сигнал (самый верхние отрывок кода):

```
signal_start_connect = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
```

и далее пробовал подключить его к кнопке с параметрами:

```
signal_start_connect2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
self.xbeeConnect = XBeeConnect(self.init_main_tab)
    self.xbeeConnect.com = str("COM" + self.ConnectValues[0])
    self.xbeeConnect.speed = int(self.ConnectValues[1])
    self.signal_start_connect2.connect(self.xbeeConnect, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    self.xbeeConnect.start()
```

И также все зависало.

Comment: вот пример, где из главного потока посылается сигнал в фоновый поток (слот `signal_obj.receive_images` в фоновом потоке выполняется) и наоборот в обратную сторону  данные из фонового потока в главный передаются, вызовами `image_viewer.on_server_start` и `image_viewer.on_received_image` слотов   [Обновление виджета QLabel PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812982/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял, что нужно сделать. 
Но если речь идет о передаче данных в поток и из потока
(используя класс QThread), то вот пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class XBeeConnect(QThread):
    ''' Потоковая задача '''

    threadSignal = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, startParm):
        super().__init__()
        self.startParm = startParm

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # делайте здесь что вым надо

        c = int(self.startParm[1])                        
        while True:
            QThread.msleep(200)
            c += 1
            self.threadSignal.emit([self.startParm[0], c])


class MainWindow(QMainWindow): #??, QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.MainWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MainWidget)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.MainWidget)   
        self.setWindowTitle('Программа управления модулями XBee S2')

        self.init_main_tab()

    def init_main_tab(self):
        self.comLbl     = QLabel('COM порт')
        self.comEdit    = QLineEdit(self)
        self.speedLbl   = QLabel('Скорость')
        self.speedEdit  = QLineEdit(self)
        self.connectBtn = QPushButton('Подключиться')
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.comLbl)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.comEdit)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.speedLbl)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.speedEdit)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.connectBtn)

        self.ConnectAllValues = [self.comEdit.text(), self.speedEdit.text()]

        #self.connectBtn.clicked.connect(lambda checked, fields=self.ConnectAllValues: self.read_values(fields))
        self.connectBtn.clicked.connect(self.read_values)

    def read_values(self): #, fields):
        """Функция считывания и передачи значений для подключения к модулю"""

        fields = [self.comEdit.text(), self.speedEdit.text()]

        self.ConnectValues = []
        for i in fields:
            #item = i.itemText(i.currentIndex())
            self.ConnectValues.append(i) 

        #Отправка в поток параметры подключения
        #self.xbeeConnect = XBeeConnect(self.OpenConnectDialog)
        self.xbeeConnect = XBeeConnect(self.ConnectValues)
        #self.xbeeConnect.com   = str("COM" + self.ConnectValues[0])
        #self.xbeeConnect.speed = int(self.ConnectValues[1])
        #self.connect(self.xbeeConnect, QtCore.SIGNAL('SendData(QString)'), self.logMessage, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.xbeeConnect.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
        self.xbeeConnect.start()

    def on_threadSignal(self, value):
        self.comLbl.setText(  "COM порт: <b>{}</b>".format(str(value[0])))
        self.speedLbl.setText("Скорость: <b>{}</b>".format(str(value[1])))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]