# Как внедрить многопоточность в PyQt?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qthread

К примеру, есть такой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Menu()

    def Menu(self):
        uic.loadUi("menu.ui", self)
        '''Здесь происходит всякая логика, смена ui и т.д.'''
        

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но в один момент нужно воспользоваться многопоточностью. К примеру, создать секундомер, который не будет замораживать приложение.

Как это можно реализовать посредством `QThread`?

**P.S.** 
Нужно сделать так, чтобы в потоке можно было использовать переменные класса окна.

Comment: Компоненты графического интерфейса не являются потокобезопасными, поэтому обращение к ним должно всегда осуществляться из одного потока.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev но что делать, если использовать многопоточность требуется?

Comment: Перейти по ссылке из первого комментария и посмотреть пример. В общих чертах: когда потоку надо что-то поменять в окне, он отправляет сигнал главному потоку, а обработчик в главном потоке выполняет необходимые изменения.

Answer (score 8):

3 разных и простых способа работы с потоками.

```
import sys
import traceback

from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QObject, QRunnable, QThread, 
                          QThreadPool, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot)
from PyQt5 import Qt


# Если при ошибке в слотах приложение просто падает без стека, 
# есть хороший способ ловить такие ошибки:
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    #import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    Qt.QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    ''' Определяет сигналы, доступные из рабочего рабочего потока Worker(QRunnable).'''

    finish   = pyqtSignal()
    error    = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result   = pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    ''' Наследует от QRunnable, настройки рабочего потока обработчика, сигналов и wrap-up. '''

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        # Хранить аргументы конструктора (повторно используемые для обработки)
        self.fn      = fn
        self.args    = args
        self.kwargs  = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
        print("\nfn=`{}`, \nargs=`{}`, kwargs=`{}`, \nself.signals=`{}`"\
              .format(fn, args, kwargs, self.signals))

        #== Добавьте обратный вызов в наши kwargs ====================================###
        kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress
        print("kwargs['progress_callback']->`{}`\n".format(kwargs['progress_callback']))

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        # Получите args/kwargs здесь; и обработка с их использованием
        try:                       # выполняем метод `execute_this_fn` переданный из Main
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) 
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:  # если ошибок не была, испускаем сигнал .result и передаем результат `result`
            self.signals.result.emit(result)      # Вернуть результат обработки
        finally:
            self.signals.finish.emit()            # Done / Готово


# Подклассификация QThread
# http://qt-project.org/doc/latest/qthread.html
class AThread(QThread):
    threadSignalAThread = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        while count < 1000:
            #time.sleep(1)
            Qt.QThread.msleep(200)
            count += 1
            self.threadSignalAThread.emit(count)


# Подкласс QObject и использование moveToThread
class SomeObject(QObject):

    finishedSomeObject     = pyqtSignal()
    threadSignalSomeObject = pyqtSignal(int)

    def long_running(self):
        print('SomeObject(QObject) id', int(QThread.currentThreadId()))
        count = 0
        while count < 150:
            Qt.QThread.msleep(100)
            count += 1
            self.threadSignalSomeObject.emit(count)   

        self.finishedSomeObject.emit()                


class MsgBoxAThread(Qt.QDialog):
    """ Класс инициализации окна для визуализации дополнительного потока 
        и кнопка для закрытия потокового окна, если поток остановлен! """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout     = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = Qt.QLabel("")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        close_btn  = Qt.QPushButton("Close Окно")
        layout.addWidget(close_btn)

        # ------- Сигнал   это только закроет окно, поток как работал, так и работает
        close_btn.clicked.connect(self.close) 

        self.setGeometry(900, 65, 400, 80)
        self.setWindowTitle('MsgBox AThread(QThread)')


class MsgBoxSomeObject(Qt.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout     = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = Qt.QLabel("")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        close_btn  = Qt.QPushButton("Close Окно")
        layout.addWidget(close_btn)

        # ------- Сигнал   это только закроет окно, поток как работал, так и работает
        close_btn.clicked.connect(self.close) 

        self.setGeometry(900, 185, 400, 80)
        self.setWindowTitle('MsgBox SomeObject(QObject)')        


class MsgBoxWorker(Qt.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout     = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = Qt.QLabel("")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        close_btn  = Qt.QPushButton("Close Окно")
        layout.addWidget(close_btn)

        # ------- Сигнал   это только закроет окно, поток как работал, так и работает
        close_btn.clicked.connect(self.close) 

        self.setGeometry(900, 300, 400, 80)
        self.setWindowTitle('MsgBox Worker(QRunnable)') 


class ExampleThread(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleThread, self).__init__(parent)

        layout     = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.lbl = Qt.QLabel("Start")
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.btnA = Qt.QPushButton("Запустить AThread(QThread)")
        layout.addWidget(self.btnA)
        self.btnB = Qt.QPushButton("Запустить SomeObject(QObject)")
        layout.addWidget(self.btnB)
        self.btnC = Qt.QPushButton("Запустить Worker(QRunnable)")
        layout.addWidget(self.btnC)
        self.progressBar = Qt.QProgressBar()
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        self.setGeometry(550, 65, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('3 разных и простых способа работы с потоками.')


        self.btnA.clicked.connect(self.using_q_thread)
        self.btnB.clicked.connect(self.using_move_to_thread)
        self.btnC.clicked.connect(self.using_q_runnable)

        self.msg       = MsgBoxAThread()  
        self.thread    = None

        self.msgSomeObject = MsgBoxSomeObject()
        self.objThread     = None

        self.counter = 0
        self.timer = Qt.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        # -------- timeout -------> def recurring_timer(self):
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.recurring_timer)   
        self.timer.start()

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Max потоков, кот. будут использоваться=`%d`" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())
        self.msgWorker = MsgBoxWorker()

        self.threadtest = QThread(self)
        self.idealthreadcount = self.threadtest.idealThreadCount()
        print("Ваша машина может обрабатывать `{}` потокa оптимально.".format(self.idealthreadcount))


    def recurring_timer(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.lbl.setText("СЧЁТЧИК цикл GUI: %d" % self.counter)        


    # ---- AThread(QThread) -----------#    
    def using_q_thread(self):
        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = AThread() 
            self.thread.threadSignalAThread.connect(self.on_threadSignalAThread)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.finishedAThread)
            self.thread.start()
            self.btnA.setText("Stop AThread(QThread)")
        else:
            self.thread.terminate()         
            self.thread = None
            self.btnA.setText("Start AThread(QThread)")    

    def finishedAThread(self):
        self.thread = None
        self.btnA.setText("Start AThread(QThread)")

    def on_threadSignalAThread(self, value):
        self.msg.label.setText(str(value))
        # Восстанавливаем визуализацию потокового окна, если его закрыли. Поток работает.
        # .setVisible(true) или .show() устанавливает виджет в видимое состояние, 
        # если видны все его родительские виджеты до окна. 
        if not self.msg.isVisible():        
            self.msg.show() 

    # --END-- AThread(QThread) -------------------#     


    # ---- SomeObject(QObject) -------------------#    
    def using_move_to_thread(self):
        if self.objThread is None:
            self.objThread = QThread()
            self.obj       = SomeObject()
            self.obj.moveToThread(self.objThread)  # Переместить в поток для выполнения

            self.obj.threadSignalSomeObject.connect(self.on_threadSignalSomeObject)
            self.obj.finishedSomeObject.connect(self.finishedSomeObject) 
            self.objThread.started.connect(self.obj.long_running)        
            self.objThread.start()                                       

            self.btnB.setText("Wait SomeObject(QObject)")
            self.btnB.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            pass 

    def finishedSomeObject(self):
        self.objThread.terminate()  
        self.objThread.wait(1)       

        self.objThread = None
        self.btnB.setEnabled(True)
        self.btnB.setText("Start SomeObject(QObject)")

    def on_threadSignalSomeObject(self, value):
        self.msgSomeObject.label.setText(str(value))
        # Восстанавливаем визуализацию потокового окна, если его закрыли. Поток работает.
        if not self.msgSomeObject.isVisible():        
            self.msgSomeObject.show()         

    # --END-- SomeObject(QObject) -------------------#    


    # ---- Worker(QRunnable) ------------------------# 
    def using_q_runnable(self):
        # Передайте функцию для выполнения
        # Любые другие аргументы, kwargs передаются функции run
        worker = Worker(self.execute_this_fn) 
        worker.signals.result.connect(self.print_output)
        worker.signals.finish.connect(self.thread_complete)
        worker.signals.progress.connect(self.progress_fn)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def progress_fn(self, n):
        self.progressBar.setValue(n)
        self.msgWorker.label.setText(str(n))
        # Восстанавливаем визуализацию потокового окна, если его закрыли. Поток работает.
        if not self.msgWorker.isVisible():        
            self.msgWorker.show()   

    def execute_this_fn(self, progress_callback):
        for n in range(0, 11):
            Qt.QThread.msleep(600)
            progress_callback.emit(n*100/10)
        return "Готово."

    def print_output(self, s):
        print("\ndef print_output(self, s):", s)

    def thread_complete(self):
        print("\nTHREAD ЗАВЕРШЕН!, self->", self)

    # --END-- Worker QRunnable) -------------------#         


    #==============================================###
    # потоки или процессы должны быть завершены    ###
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = Qt.QMessageBox.question\
        (self, 'Информация',
            "Вы уверены, что хотите закрыть приложение?",
             Qt.QMessageBox.Yes,
             Qt.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == Qt.QMessageBox.Yes:
            if self.thread:
                self.thread.quit()
            del self.thread
            self.msg.close()

            if self.objThread:
                self.objThread.setTerminationEnabled(True)
                self.objThread.terminate()     
                self.objThread.wait(1)   
            self.msgSomeObject.close()

            # закрыть поток Worker(QRunnable)
            self.msgWorker.close()

            super(ExampleThread, self).closeEvent(event)
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    mw  = ExampleThread()
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стоит упомянуть [откуда код взяли](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6783194/4279)

Comment: @jfs верно был вдохновлен этим постом, но внес и свою лепту

Answer (score 3):

**Вот пример QThread**

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class SenderMessage(QObject):
    text_value = pyqtSignal(str)
    int_value = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.text_value.emit("Привет!")
        sleep(1.5)
        self.text_value.emit("Я PyQt5.")
        sleep(1.5)
        self.text_value.emit("Мы сегодня тестируем...")
        sleep(1.5)
        self.text_value.emit("Класс QThread.")
        for i in range(10, 101, 1):
            sleep(0.1)
            self.int_value.emit(i)
        self.text_value.emit("Тест завершён.")
        sleep(1.5)
        self.text_value.emit("Приложение будет закрыто.")

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        try:
            self.setWindowTitle("Многопоточность")
            self.setGeometry(400, 200, 350, 80)

            self.label = QLabel(self)
            self.label.setGeometry(0, 0, 350, 50)
            self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(25, 156, 25);\
                font: italic 18pt MS Shell Dlg 2; border: 5px solid red;")

            self.danger = "QProgressBar::chunk {background: QLinearGradient( 
x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0,stop: 0 #FF0350,stop: 0.4999 #00d920,stop: 0.5 
#FF0019,stop: 1 #ff0000 );border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom- 
left-radius: 5px;border: .px solid black;}"
            self.safe = "QProgressBar::chunk {background: QLinearGradient( 
x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0,stop: 0 #78d,stop: 0.4999 #46a,stop: 0.5 
#45a,stop: 1 #238 );border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;border-bottom-left- 
radius: 7px;border: 1px solid black;}"


            self.progress_bar = QProgressBar(self)
            self.progress_bar.setStyleSheet(self.safe)
            self.progress_bar.setValue(10)
            self.progress_bar.setGeometry(0, 50, 350, 30)

            self.thread = QThread()

            self.sender_message = SenderMessage()

            self.timer = QTimer(self)
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.close)
            self.timer.start(17000)

            self.sender_message.moveToThread(self.thread)
            self.sender_message.text_value.connect(self.signalHandlerText)
            self.sender_message.int_value.connect(self.signalHandlerInt)

            self.thread.started.connect(self.sender_message.run)
            self.thread.start()
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
    def signalHandlerText(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

    def signalHandlerInt(self, value):
        self.progress_bar.setValue(value)

        if self.progress_bar.value() < 80:
            self.progress_bar.setStyleSheet(self.safe)
        else:
            self.progress_bar.setStyleSheet(self.danger)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

В первую очередь стоит рассмотреть вариант без потоков. К примеру, для реализации секундомера, чтобы отложить выполнение функции по времени, можно рассмотреть методы QTimer класса. Для сетевых соединений, чтобы не использовать блокирующих функций типа `requests.get()`, можно рассмотреть использование *асинхронного* интерфейса такого как `QNetworkAccessManager`.

Есть несколько (в том числе уже устаревших) способов использовать потоки в qt5 ([QThread, QRunnable, QThreadPool, QConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html)). Так как большинство GUI методов не являются потокобезопасными, то общение из фонового потока с GUI потоком можно с *помощью сигналов* организовывать. Пример: [Обновление виджета QLabel PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812982/23044).

Не обязательно даже QThread использовать. Сигналы можно посылать из обычных Питон-потоков, [пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/fd292613a51bc55f224b6d74f84fc316).