# Организовать фоновые потоки на PyQt5

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5

Помимо GUI мне нужно несколько фоновых потоков, запускаемые вместе с GUI, я смотрел в сторону threading, но как я понял там GIL не дает потокам работать параллельно. QThread работает так же? Как вообще я могу запустить 2-3 параллельных потоков, которые не будут ждать друг друга(Если не используют одни и те же данные)? Можно пример с отправкой данных в GUI? Пожалуйста...

Comment: На самом деле примеров очень много, вот например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840239/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-pyqt/840447#840447

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения "параллельности" между классами `Thread` и `QTread` действительно нет разницы, за исключением того что экземпляр `QTread` в состоянии отправлять сообщения главному окну через механизм слотов. В ГУИ отдельные потоки создаются как правило чтобы интерфейс не подвисал. Редко нужно реально много считать и делать это в отдельных процессах. Если у вас работа с сетью или файлами - вот пример на PySide2

```
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QProgressBar, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QFile, QObject, Slot, Signal, QThread
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

class LoaderDataChunk(QThread):

    valueChanged = Signal([int, int], name='val')

    def __init__(self, id, q, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.id = id
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        # что-то делаем...

        # посылаем сигнал для разморозки интерфейса главного приложения
        self.valueChanged.emit(self.id, i)

        # если работаем через очередь - основной поток может безопасно подождать окончания
        self.q.task_done()

class Downloader(QObject):
    def __init__(self, ui_file, parent=None):
        super(Downloader, self).__init__()
        ui_file = QFile(filename)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.window = loader.load(ui_file)
        ui_file.close()

        self.window.setWindowIcon(QIcon(iconfile))

    def loadData(self):
        chunks = []  # наша огромная задача

        self.q = Queue()

        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            self.q.put(chunk)
            pg = QProgressBar()
            pg.setValue(0)
            loader = LoaderDataChunk(i, self.q self)
            loader.valueChanged.connect(self.showProgress)
            loader.start()

        # морозим интерфейс до выполнения задачи
        self.window.frame.setEnabled(False)
        self.window.menu.setEnabled(False)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.waitResult)
        thread.start()

    @Slot(int, int)
    def showProgress(self, id, value):
        self.progress_list[id].setValue(value)

    def waitResult(self):
        print('start waiting...')
        self.q.join()
        self.window.frame.setEnabled(True)
        self.window.menu.setEnabled(True)
```

Можно сделать и по другому - не создавать много потоков, а работать асинхронно. Тогда нужен лишь один поток, в нём запросить новый eventloop, и в этом лупе уже крутить все операции. Опять же, этот второй поток должен наследовать от `QTread`