# Как отключить кнопку в PyQt5 на время выполнения кода

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, qpushbutton

Подключаю кнопку:

```
self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.parse)
```

И хотелось бы, чтобы она отключалась на время выполнения **`self.parse()`**.
Я пробовал сделать это через **`setEnabled`**, но *PyQt5* видимо запоминает клик и прогоняет метод еще раз.

Проблема в том что **`self.parse()`** выполняется около трех секунд и если много раз нажать на кнопку программа зависнет на какое-то время.

**UPD**:

```
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.ui = main_window.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.parse()

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_button)

        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.ship_info)

        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.back_page)

        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.update_data)

        self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.parse)

    def parse(self):

        self.ui.pushButton_5.setEnabled(False)

        **Циклы, мульпоточные GET-запросы, парсинг и все такое**

        self.ui.pushButton_5.setEnabled(True)
```

Comment: Не может быть, чтобы PyQt5 "запоминал клик и прогонял код слота еще раз". Можете показать больше кода?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, добавил

Comment: А если повесить парсинг на pressed, то тоже дважды вызывается? В целом надо делать, конечно, через потоки –

Comment: @ОлегСветовидов я добавил в свой ответ решение, которое вас устроит пока вы не доберетесь до потоков.

Comment: @S.Nick а не могли бы вы направить меня к правильному решению? Я не свосем понимаю как я могу сделать это через потоки.

Comment: @ОлегСветовидов посмотритре https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840239/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-pyqt/840447#840447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Графический интерфейс пользователя (GUI) имеет цикл по умолчанию, 
и он блокируется циклами, которые занимают слишком много времени 
и генерируют зависание приложения или неадекватное поведение.

Простой способ решить эту проблему - использовать `processEvents()`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Запустите процес.", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.parse)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self) 
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn1) 

    def parse(self):
        self.btn1.setText("Выполняется процесс, ожидайте ...")
        self.btn1.setEnabled(False)                            # <----- 

        for i in range(500000) :
            # Делайте что-нибудь
            qApp.processEvents()                               # <-----                  
            pass

        self.btn1.setEnabled(True)                             # <----- 
        self.btn1.setText("Запустите процес.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(300, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Попробуйте `setVisible(bool)`

Но все идет к тому, что вам надо обзаводиться потоками :)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("btn1 Enabled", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.parse1)

        self.btn2 = QPushButton("btn2 Visible", self)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.parse2)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget) #(self) #(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn1, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn2, 1, 0) 

    def parse1(self):
        self.btn1.setEnabled(False)
        QTimer.singleShot(500, self.parse1_1)

    def parse1_1(self):
        print("setEnabled(False)")
        QThread.msleep(3000)    
        self.btn1.setEnabled(True)
        print("setEnabled(True)")
        self.btn1.show()

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def parse2(self):
        self.btn2.setVisible(False)                        # <---
        QTimer.singleShot(200, self.parse2_1)         

    def parse2_1(self):        
        print("setVisible(False)")
        QThread.msleep(3000)    
        self.btn2.setVisible(True)                         # <---
        print("setVisible(True)")        
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]