# Многопоточность Python PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pyqt5, gui

Не получается организовать многопоточность в двух функциях с подвязкой PyQt5

```
    def Scanner(self) -> object:
               mas = [20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 42, 43, 53, 67, 69, 80, 110, 115, 123, 137, 138, 139, 143, 161, 179, 443, 445,514, 515, 993, 995]
               host = self.lineEdit_2.text()
               try:
                   ipaddress.ip_network(host)
                   for port in mas:
                       s = socket.socket()
                       s.settimeout(1)
                       try:
                           s.connect((host, port))
                           per2 = (str(port) + ' port open!')

                           self.textEdit_5.setText(per2)
                           print(per2)
                       except socket.error:
                           per3 = (str(port) + ' port locked!')
                           self.textEdit_5.append(per3)
               except ValueError:
                      QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error!', 'Invalid IP!')

    theardforce = threading.Thread(target=Scanner(self),name = "Scanner")
    theardforce.start()
    theardforce.join()
```

```
    def list(self, request=None):

       per1 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
       try:
           ipaddress.ip_network(per1)



           url = 'http://www.ip-score.com/ajax_handler/get_bls'

           blacklist = [
                    'access.redhawk.org', 'b.barracudacentral.org', 'bl.shlink.org', 'bl.spamcannibal.org',
                    'bl.spamcop.net', 'bl.tiopan.com', 'blackholes.wirehub.net', 'blacklist.sci.kun.nl',
                    'block.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'blocked.hilli.dk', 'bogons.cymru.com', 'cart00ney.surriel.com',
                    'cbl.abuseat.org', 'cblless.anti-spam.org.cn', 'dev.null.dk', 'dialup.blacklist.jippg.org',
                    'dialups.mail-abuse.org', 'dialups.visi.com', 'dnsbl.abuse.ch', 'dnsbl.anticaptcha.net',
                    'dnsbl.antispam.or.id', 'dnsbl.dronebl.org', 'dnsbl.justspam.org', 'dnsbl.kempt.net',
                    'dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'dnsbl.tornevall.org', 'dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net', 'duinv.aupads.org',
                    'dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net', 'dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net', 'dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'dul.ru',
                    'escalations.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'hil.habeas.com', 'black.junkemailfilter.com',
                    'http.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'intruders.docs.uu.se', 'ips.backscatterer.org',
                    'korea.services.net', 'l2.apews.org', 'mail-abuse.blacklist.jippg.org',
                    'misc.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'msgid.bl.gweep.ca', 'new.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
                    'no-more-funn.moensted.dk', 'old.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'opm.tornevall.org', 'pbl.spamhaus.org',
                    'proxy.bl.gweep.ca', 'psbl.surriel.com', 'pss.spambusters.org.ar', 'rbl.schulte.org',
                    'rbl.snark.net', 'recent.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'relays.bl.gweep.ca', 'relays.bl.kundenserver.de',
                    'relays.mail-abuse.org', 'relays.nether.net', 'rsbl.aupads.org', 'sbl.spamhaus.org',
                    'smtp.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'spam.olsentech.net',
                    'spamguard.leadmon.net', 'spamsources.fabel.dk', 'tor.dnsbl.sectoor.de', 'ubl.unsubscore.com',
                    'web.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'xbl.spamhaus.org', 'zen.spamhaus.org', 'zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
                    'dnsbl.inps.de', 'dyn.shlink.org', 'rbl.megarbl.net', 'bl.mailspike.net']

           for server in blacklist:
                    try:
                        data = {'ip': per1, 'server': server}

                        response = requests.post(url, data=data, timeout=3)

                        if response.status_code != 200:
                            raise ValueError('Expected 200 OK')

                        data = response.json()

                        rating = data[data.keys()[0]]

                        if rating != "":
                            self.textEdit_4.setText(server + "LISTED " + rating)

                    except:
                          self.textEdit_4.append("NOT LISTED: " + server)

       except ValueError:
             QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error!', 'Invalid IP!')

    theardforce1 = threading.Thread(target=list(self),name = "list")
    theardforce1.start()
    theardforce1.join(
```

Comment: Любой доступ к элементам пользовательского интерфейса разрешен только из основного потока Qt. 
Обратите внимание, что доступ означает не только чтение/запись свойств виджета, но и создание; 
любая попытка сделать это из других потоков приводит к графическим проблемам 
или несистематическому поведению в лучшем случае и к сбою в худшем (в более частом) случае. 
Единственный правильный способ сделать это - использовать QThread с (возможно) настраиваемыми сигналами: 
это позволяет Qt правильно ставить сигналы в очередь и реагировать на них, 
когда он действительно может их обработать.

Comment: На самом деле проблемы многопоточности много раз уже обсуждались. 
Посмотрите например пост  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840239/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-pyqt/840447#840447
 и выберите что вам больше нравится и понятнее.