# Предупреждение при выводе текста в QPlainTextEdit, что они означают? Вывод работает потоком

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, qthread, qplaintextedit

Столкнулся с проблемой. В виджет `QPlainTextEdit`, строчки выводятся криво. Это не постоянно, но проблема уже с самого начала работы мешает. Помогает перезапуска кода.

Перед запуском кода вылезает предупреждение, либо вот такое, оно ничего особенного за собой не несёт:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextBlock'
> (Make sure 'QTextBlock' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
> (Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

Второе предупреждение, вместе взятое с первым:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextBlock'
> (Make sure 'QTextBlock' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
> (Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
> QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
> QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
> QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted

Ну и, в итоге, выходит вот такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если скопировать, то на самом деле, с текстом всё впорядке:

```
 =============================================================================================================
15/06/2021 | 18:28:11 > BOT CONNECTED - Heimdallr#8868 :)
15/06/2021 | 18:28:11 > config> LOG CHANNEL : 820631085271875587
15/06/2021 | 18:28:11 > config> CHANNEL VoIP: 820631085271875587
 =============================================================================================================
```

Вывод работает потоком:

```
class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        window = QWidget()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(window)
        self.PVELogs = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(parent.centralwidget)
        self.PVELogs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 801, 491))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.PVELogs.setFont(font)
        self.PVELogs.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.PVELogs.setReadOnly(True)
        self.PVELogs.setPlainText("")

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.PVELogs.appendPlainText(msg)
        self.PVELogs.update() # +++

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        i = ''
        self.msleep(2000)
        self.threadSignal.emit(i) # < Выводит текст.
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

        START_BOT = bot.loop.create_task(bot.run(config.BOT_TOKEN))
        ON_READY = bot.loop.create_task(on_ready())

        bot.loop.run_until_complete(START_BOT)
        bot.loop.run_until_complete(ON_READY)
        bot.loop.run_forever()
```

Проблема возникает когда подключаю **`on_ready()`** через `WorkThread()`, с помощью `asyncio`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("FUNC: ON_READY ")
    logging.warning(" =============================================================================================================")
    log(f'BOT CONNECTED - {bot.user} :)')
    log('config> LOG CHANNEL : %d' % (lchanID))
    if config.USEVCSTATS == True:
        log('config> CHANNEL VoIP: %d' % (chanID))
        logging.warning(" =============================================================================================================\n")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
```

---

Дополнил `def emit()` - **`self.PVELogs.update()`**, на время помогло, но код стал дополняться и проблема вновь пришла.

---

[Визуализация кода](https://pastebin.com/5tzmZpf7)

[Весь код](https://pastebin.com/GZU8Zadc)

Comment: Эти сообщения говорят о том, что 
вы не можете взаимодействовать с виджетами в других потоках. 
Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] .

Comment: @S.Nick, если кусочек кода отправлю, без объяснения. Подойдёт?

Comment: попробуйте добавит, но код должен быть минимальный (без лишних строк, которые не влияют на проблему данного вопроса ) и воспроизводимым (код копируется, запускается и получаем ошибки, о которых вы пишите)

Comment: @S.Nick, проверьте. Стараюсь максимально понятно,честно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не могу проверить ваш пример, но предложу попробовать следующее:

```
...
    
class MySignal(QObject):                                                  # +++ 
    log_signal = pyqtSignal(str)                                          # +++
   
 
class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        
        sels.mySignal = MySignal()                                        # +++
 
        ''' # !!! перенес в class Main
        window = QWidget()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(window)
        self.PVELogs = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(parent.centralwidget)
        self.PVELogs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 801, 491))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.PVELogs.setFont(font)
        self.PVELogs.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.PVELogs.setReadOnly(True)
        self.PVELogs.setPlainText("")
        '''
        
    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        
        sels.mySignal.log_signal.emit(msg)                   # +++ <---- emit signal here
        
        ''' # !!! перенес в class Main
        self.PVELogs.appendPlainText(msg)
        self.PVELogs.update()
        '''
...
        
#                                   vvvvvvv <---------------------------- ???        
# class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QWidget, MainInterface):
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, MainInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.myclose = True
 
        logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
# +++        
        logTextBox.mySignal.log_signal.connect(self.append_plain_text)    # +++
        
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(logTextBox)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        root_logger = logging.getLogger()
        #root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        handler = logging.FileHandler('App.log', 'a', 'utf-8') 
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s, %(asctime)s, [%(levelname)s], %(message)s'))
        root_logger.addHandler(handler)
 
        self.PVELogs.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        
        self.thread = WorkThread()
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.func2)
             
        self.onPVE.clicked.connect(self.func1)
        self.onPVE.clicked.connect(self.change_button)
        self.offPVE.clicked.connect(self.offwhite)
 
        logging.warning(" ========================================= VALHEIMBY LOGS - v1.0.0 ==========================================")
        logging.warning(" =============================================================================================================\n")

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvb
        self.PVELogs = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.PVELogs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 801, 491))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.PVELogs.setFont(font)
        self.PVELogs.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.PVELogs.setReadOnly(True)
        self.PVELogs.setPlainText("")

    def append_plain_text(self, msg):
        self.PVELogs.appendPlainText(msg)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   

...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Поражаюсь вашей гениальностью! Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно почитать, как вообще работают потоки и потоки Pyqt. Посоветуйте лучшее.

Comment: @iframe пожалуйста. Все собирается по крупице. Вот обобщенный пост по работе с потоками https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840239/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-pyqt/840447#840447 . А вообще-то я лично уже много публиковал ответов по данной тематике https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&q=user%3a217323%20QThread