# Потоки и сигналы

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, многопоточность, qthread

Имеется следующий код:

```
import time
import sys

#from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QPushButton,
    QTextEdit, 
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget
)

from threading import Thread


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
   
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.output = QTextEdit()
        self.output.setReadOnly(True)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.output)

        self.startButton = QPushButton("Start")
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def task(self):
        while True:
            obj = Actions()
            obj.do()
            time.sleep(3)
            
    def start(self):
        t1 = Thread(target=self.task)
        t1.start()



class Actions():
    
    def do(self):
        window.output.append("...")   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

При выполнении данного примера (для *PyQt5*) получаю предупреждение cледующего плана:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
> (Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

[Здеcь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295241/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-pyqt5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82) и [здеcь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840239/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-pyqt/840447) сказано, что:

- нельзя взаимодействовать с виджетами в других потоках, поэтому этот варнинг и выводится
- когда потоку надо что-то поменять в окне, он отправляет сигнал главному потоку, а обработчик в главном потоке выполняет необходимые изменения

Как реализовать второй пункт? Есть ли хорошие туториалы с примерами по этой теме?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужны дополнительные библиотеки для организации работы с потоками.

Читаем [**Signals & Slots**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html)

Смотрим [**3 разных и простых способа работы с потоками**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840239/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-pyqt/840447#840447).

```
import sys
#import time
#from threading import Thread
#from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import ( QApplication, QPushButton,
    QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal                          # +++


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Thread(QThread):
    dateSignal = pyqtSignal(str)                                      # +++
    
    def __init__(self):    
        super().__init__()
        self.num = 1
        
    def run(self):        
        while True:
        
            # тут вы выполняете какие-то длительные действия
            text = f'... {self.num}'
            
            # тут вы испускаете сигнал и передаете какие-то данные
            self.dateSignal.emit(text)                                # +++
            #           2000 мс
            self.msleep(2000) 
            self.num += 1            
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.output = QTextEdit()
        self.output.setReadOnly(True)

        self.startButton = QPushButton("Start")
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.output)        
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        
        self.thread = Thread()                                     # +++
        self.thread.dateSignal.connect(self.update_data)           # +++

    def start(self):
#-        t1 = Thread(target=self.task)
#-        t1.start()
        self.thread.start()                                        # +++

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def update_data (self, text):                                  # +++
        self.output.append(text) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


'''
    def task(self):
        while True:
            obj = Actions()
            obj.do()
            time.sleep(3)
            
    def start(self):
        t1 = Thread(target=self.task)
        t1.start()

class Actions():
    
    def do(self):
        window.output.append("...")   
'''            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сердечно благодарю!

Comment: @Alexey я рад что помог вам. Удачи.