# Как послать изображение через сокет

Tags: python, сокет, изображения, pil

Как можно реализовать передачу изображения от клиента к серверу используя PIL `ImageGrab.grab()`. Искал в гугле, нечего подходящего по этой теме не нашёл.

Comment: Делал пример отправки с клиента на сервер картинку, чтобы сервер возвращал миниатюру: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/fde3a7efe25704806272fa7ffc162e6315d51bce/socket__tcp__examples/send_img__recv_thumbnail Его несложно будет переделать, да и есть от чего отталкиваться

Comment: [пример сервера на qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/813204/23044), который показывает полученные по сокету картинки. [Пример кода с пулом](https://gist.github.com/zed/fd292613a51bc55f224b6d74f84fc316)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buf = BytesIO()

img = ImageGrab.grab()
img.save(buf, 'png')

some_socket.sendall(buf.getvalue())
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: @ЕгорВасильев [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: для самодостаточности можно добавить явное словесное описание (одно соединение -- одна картинка, голые байты в png формате), импорты и что-нибудь вроде socket.create_connection() вызова или хотя бы сослаться на [пример](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example)

Comment: @jfs не будет ли это избыточной информацией, скрывающей суть ответа?

Comment: вам решать какая форма вашего ответа будет наиболее полезна будущим читателям