# Как создать демона в Python, который будет отслеживать состояние булевой переменной класса?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5

Например, у меня есть класс интерфейса(Pyqt) внутри него создан еще один класс интерфейса, который создан для оформления. Как сделать так чтобы из внутреннего класса поступил сигнал во внешний класс при изменении какого либо поля класса?

Comment: традиционный daemon исполняется в фоне и с пользователем не взаимодействует, поэтому если под словом интерфейс(PyQt) вы GUI подразумевали (слово оформление на это намекает), то у вас тут каша какая-то из несовместимых терминов. Стоит  *минимальный* пример кода попробовать создать, который демонстрирует проблему [mcve]

Comment: вот пример кода в противоположном направлении: [сервер, запущенный в фоновом потоке, посылает сигналы в GUI](https://gist.github.com/zed/fd292613a51bc55f224b6d74f84fc316) Связанный вопрос [Обновление виджета QLabel PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812982/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это же классический паттерн проектирования наблюдатель получается. Вот адаптировал из wiki вам пример. `BoolModificator` - класс, в котором что-то твориться. `BooloObserver` класс, который ожидает изменений - наблюдатель. Ну а `modify` метод который триггерит изменение переменной у наблюдателя. 
Вложенность класса в класс - ну ссылайтесь просто правильно.

```
class Observer:
    def update(self, message):
        pass

class Observable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []
    def register(self, observer):
        self.observers.append(observer)
    def notify_observers(self, message):
        for observer in self.observers:
            observer.update(message)

class BoolModificator(Observable):
    def modify(self, news):
        self.notify_observers(news)

class BooloObserver(Observer):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.my_bool = False
    def update(self, new_bool):
        old_bool = self.my_bool
        self.my_bool = new_bool
        print('{}: my_bool = {} (was {})'.format(self.name, self.my_bool, old_bool))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = BoolModificator()
    event.register(BooloObserver('first'))
    event.modify(True)

# first: my_bool = True (was False)
```